# Coefficient of expression that involves derivatives

Tags: simplifying-expressions, coefficients

I have a long expression, only representative terms are given below. As a first step, I want to collect terms in terms of u[x,t] and its derivatives.  The second step is to make those coefficients equal to zero as separate equations.
For example, if I have the expression:

```
xpr=a[x, t, u]*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t] + 2*Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t]*
Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]*Derivative[0, 0, 1][b][x, t, u] + 
2*u[x, t]*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]^2*Derivative[0, 0, 1][b][x, t, u] + 
 2*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]*Derivative[1, 1][u][x, t]*Derivative[0, 0, 1][c][x, t, u]+2*Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t]*
Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]*Derivative[0, 0, 1][d][x, t, u];
```

The first step should result in:

```
stp1=a[x, t, u]*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t] + 2*u[x, t]*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]^2*
Derivative[0, 0, 1][b][x, t, u] + 2*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]*
 Derivative[1, 1][u][x, t]*Derivative[0, 0, 1][c][x, t, u] + 
Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t]*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]*
 (2*Derivative[0, 0, 1][b][x, t, u] + 2*Derivative[0, 0, 1][d][x, t, u])
```

The last step will give rise to:

```
 eqns={a[x, t, u] == 0, 2*Derivative[0, 0, 1][b][x, t, u] == 0, 
  2*Derivative[0, 0, 1][c][x, t, u] == 0, 
  2*Derivative[0, 0, 1][b][x, t, u] + 2*Derivative[0, 0, 1][d][x, t, u] == 0},
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
xpr = a[x, t, u]*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t] + 
   2*Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t]*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]*
    Derivative[0, 0, 1][b][x, t, u] + 
   2*u[x, t]*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]^2*
    Derivative[0, 0, 1][b][x, t, u] + 
   2*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]*Derivative[1, 1][u][x, t]*
    Derivative[0, 0, 1][c][x, t, u];

eqns = Thread[((List @@ xpr) /. {Derivative[_, _][u][__] :> 1, 
       u[_, _] :> 1}) == 0] // DeleteDuplicates

 (* {a[x, t, u] == 0, 
   2*Derivative[0, 0, 1][b][x, t, u] == 0, 
   2*Derivative[0, 0, 1][c][x, t, u] == 0} *)
```

**EDIT:** For the clarified question

```
Clear["Global`*"]

xpr = a[x, t, u]*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t] + 
   2*Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t]*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]*
    Derivative[0, 0, 1][b][x, t, u] + 
   2*u[x, t]*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]^2*Derivative[0, 0, 1][b][x, t, u] + 
   2*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]*Derivative[1, 1][u][x, t]*
    Derivative[0, 0, 1][c][x, t, u] + 
   2*Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t]*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]*
    Derivative[0, 0, 1][d][x, t, u];

eqns = Thread[
   DeleteCases[
     CoefficientList[xpr, 
       DeleteCases[
        Variables[
         Level[xpr, {-2}]], _?(FreeQ[#, u[__] | Derivative[__][u]] &)]] // 
      Flatten, 0] == 0] // Simplify

(* {a[x, t, u] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][c][x, t, u] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][b][x, t, u] + 
       Derivative[0, 0, 1][d][x, t, u] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][b][x, t, u] == 0} *)
```

The `Simplify` removes the constants (e.g., `2`) that are common to all terms of an equation.

Comment: Many thanks. However, I need to group similar terms that have common u[x,t] and its derivatives before applying your function.

Comment: @qahtah - please edit your question to clarify what you want and provide explicit examples of the types of inputs that need to be addressed.

Comment: thanks for your help. I edited the question, hopefully it is clear now.

Comment: That is exactly what I need. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Bob,  Unfortunately, the code doesn't work as expected, a simple example if xpr=-(u[x, t]^2*Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t]*Derivative[0, 0, 1][\[Eta]][x, t, u]) - Derivative[0, 2][u][x, t]*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]*Derivative[0, 0, 1][\[Xi]][x, t, u]; it doesn't group these two terms.

Comment: @qahtah - It is not clear why the terms in your comment should be grouped. The factors of `u` and its derivatives are not the same, they are not even of the same order even if the individual factors were somehow considered equivalent. You need to specify explicit rules to be used to consider terms as "groupable".

Comment: Bob thank you for persistent effort. I will have a deeper look at my problem and get back to you if needed. Many thanks again.